# Calculation of Lebesgue integral over a pyramid

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $ \triangle_{n}\left(h\right)=\left\{ x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}\thinspace:\thinspace x_{1},...,x_{n}\geq0\thinspace\thinspace,x_{1}+...+x_{n}\leq h\right\}  $

I need to check for which $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n$ the function $$ x_{1}^{\alpha_{1}}...x_{n}^{\alpha_{n}} $$ is integrable over $ \triangle_{n}\left(h\right) $ and to calculate the integral, where the integral is Lebesgue integral.

Im struggling with this one for a while and still have no clue how to find condition on the $\alpha$s to get integrability. Any hints or help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: To find some sufficient conditions, consider the integral of the same function over $[0,h]^n$.  To find some necessary conditions, consider the integral of the same function over $[0,h/n]^n$.

Comment: Wait, what? How is this not integrable for all alphas? The function is continuous so its Riemann integral (which thus exists) must coincede with its Lebesgue integral of that function.